# Build and push image to DockerHub from CircleCI

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm new to CI / CD and I'm trying with CircleCI to build and push my app on DockerHub.

I researched some things on the internet, and tried some things, without success.

I'm having an error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
sudo docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
sudo docker tag $HUB_NAME $DOCKER_LOGIN/$HUB_NAME
sudo docker push $DOCKER_LOGIN/$HUB_NAMEr
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Exited with code 1
```

My config-yml where I am having trouble:

```
# run tests!
  - run: mvn integration-test

  - setup_remote_docker
  - run:
      name: Build and deploy docker images
      command: |
        docker build -t $HUB_NAME:latest .

  - deploy:
      name: Push application Docker image
      command: |
        sudo docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
        sudo docker tag $HUB_NAME $DOCKER_LOGIN/$HUB_NAME
        sudo docker push $DOCKER_LOGIN/$HUB_NAME
```

Comment: What executor and/or image are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you should not be using `sudo docker` in your `login`, `tag` and `push` commands.

Just use `docker login`, `docker tag` and `docker push` without `sudo` and you should be good to go.

## Explanation

The whole point of the [`setup_remote_docker`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#setup_remote_docker) step, which you **are** using in your configuration, is to set the environment variables that allow the docker command to access a remote docker environment with the current docker user.

In your pipeline output, if you open the step with the label `Setup a remote Docker engine`, you'll likely see an output like:

```
Allocating a remote Docker Engine

[ ... skip some output ...]

Remote Docker engine created. Using VM '...'
Created container accessible with:
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/tmp/docker-certs(...)
  DOCKER_HOST=tcp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY
  DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=ZZZZ
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
  NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost,circleci-internal-outer-build-agent,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY

[ ... some more output ...]
```

If you `sudo` into another user, you'll be missing out on those environment variables, and the `docker` command will attempt to connect to the standard docker unix socket in the local machine. Which is why you see:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Check the [Building Docker Images](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/) documentation to see that they don't use `sudo` anywhere.

You probably copied those `sudo` commands from your own environment where your local machine restricts access to the docker unix socket.

Comment: @britt-kelly, without seeing your configuration, it's hard to tell whether you have the same issue as @peter-parker, but it's likely you don't. Please check your configuration against [the docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/), in particular check whether the `setup_remote_docker` step is used correctly. If you believe it is, then I suggest you ask your own question with your details, or contact CircleCI with your issue.